# Regular Expression to capture digits in multiline text preceded by specific keywords

Tags: php, regex

I have a text for a .scss file and I want to update values in a nested map block. It looks like this:

```
$header-styles: (
  small: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 32),
    'h2': ('font-size': 28),
    'h3': ('font-size': 24),
    'h4': ('font-size': 21),
    'h5': ('font-size': 20),
    'h6': ('font-size': 18),
  ),
  large: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 52),
    'h2': ('font-size': 42),
    'h3': ('font-size': 36),
    'h4': ('font-size': 21),
    'h5': ('font-size': 21),
    'h6': ('font-size': 18),
  ),
  xxlarge: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 64),
    'h2': ('font-size': 52),
    'h3': ('font-size': 36),
    'h4': ('font-size': 28),
    'h5': ('font-size': 21),
    'h6': ('font-size': 20),
  ),
);
```

I am running a couple foreach loops that will give me access to the sizes; small, large, xxlarge, the heading sizes, h1–h6, and I want to read the number value of each and update with a new number.

Using https://regexr.com/78v0o I created a pattern that works, but in my PHP preg_match function it's only matching the first heading size; h1.

The pattern in my loop looks like this:

```
$pattern = "/(?: $breakpoint:[\s\n()':, \-a-z0-9]*?$size.*)(\d{1,3})/s";
```

An example would be:

```
(?: large:[\s\n()':, \-a-z0-9]*?h3.*)([0-9]{1,2})
```

I'm expecting to get a set of digits, for example in the above pattern, i'm expecting to get '36'.

There have been a few iterations before that were close but they're always a little too greedy.

Comment: Try this: `/\blarge:[\s()':,\w-]*?h3.*\K\b[0-9]+/`

Comment: You just have to make the `.*?` non-greedy  after the `h3` `[ ]large:[a-z0-9\s '-),\-:\n]*?h3.*?([0-9]{1,2})` https://regex101.com/r/B4nb0R/1 . Or even `[ ]large:[\s '-),\-0-:a-z\n]*?h3.*?([0-9]{1,2})` https://regex101.com/r/v8eJiq/1

Comment: Thank you @anubhava, that was a nice, clean pattern and worked perfectly. Side note: I had to modify it to also detect \. because I was replacing some of the values with floats, and the pattern wouldn't match the period, thus skipping heading values after one with a decimal and causing me a serious headache.